# Compare 'e.target' to a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, jquery-events

What I want to do:

```
( clickedObject === someDiv ) //returns true or false
```

What I tried

```
( $(e.target) === $('.selector') ); //returns a false negative.
```

My workaround

```
( $(e.target).attr('class') === $('.selector').attr('class') ); //works as intended, not so clean though.
```

What is the right way to compare the object I clicked to an object in the DOM?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To check if `e.target` has this class you can use the `hasClass` function.

```
if ($(e.target).hasClass("selector"))
```

Or, if you really want to compare objects, note that jQuery selectors return a collection of items, so I think you'll want

```
if (e.target === $('.selector')[0])
```

Comment: I like this answer, because it describes why my approach did not work. jQuery returns a collection of items.

Answer (score 40):

You're close. Use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) instead:

```
if($(e.target).is('.selector')) {
    // Your code
}
```

The trick here is that you wrap `e.target` in a jQuery object to allow it access to all the useful jQuery methods.

If you're just seeing whether `e.target` has a certain class, try using [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) in place of `.is()`:

```
if($(e.target).hasClass('selector')) {
    // Your code
}
```

Either method works, although `.hasClass()` is a little clearer as to what the code does, and is faster than using `.is()`

Comment: if you already have a reference to the element you want to compare against, the following works: $myButton.is(e.target)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the element that the event is attached to you can use `$(this)`, or if you want to find which element triggered the event use `$(event.target)`.

Below is an example of both of these.

http://jsfiddle.net/Phunky/TbJef/

Unless you're using event delegation these will be the same though and if there the same element.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously using `.is()` function is the best solution here.

If you find yourself doing such comparison, try to check if it is possible to use embedded jQuery mechanisms like this:

```
$(element).on("click", ".selector", function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Second argument in the `.on()` method is a target selector. When using this construction (read more: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) there will be no need to make any additional comparisons.

https://jsfiddle.net/m5zysufy/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).click(function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var container = $('.dropdown-list').attr('class');
  if ($(e.target).attr('class') == container) {
    $('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle();
  } else {
    $('.header .header-elem .dropdown-nav .dropdown-menu').slideUp();
  }
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer