# complex if condition using e.target in modal.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was just looking at the source of modal.js and came across the following difficulty . i don't understand the below if statement quite well :

```
if (this.$element[0] !== e.target && !this.$element.has(e.target).length)
```

ok i do understand parts of it , but i don't entirely understand it .

i did see a few helpful resources that did help me a big , but i still can't completely understand that if statement :

i saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606269/compare-e-target-to-a-jquery-object)  .

i also read [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_target.asp) .

but i still can't completely grasp whats happening .

so heres what i understand so far .

in the below line :

```
if (this.$element[0] !== e.target && !this.$element.has(e.target).length)
```

this.$element is a native JS HTML emelemt and we are checking to see if it matches e.target , what about the next condition ?

```
!this.$element.has(e.target).length
```

what are we checking for here ?? has(e.target) ? i have never seen that before .

i have see something like `this.$element.hasClass('classname')` , but whats with the `has(e.target).length` . ?

**I would be really grateful , if somebody could explain with an example , what that line is doing**

the line can be found on git too , [line 135](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L135).

Thank you.

Gautam.

Answer (score 0):

It is checking that it contains the element or not.

refer: [event.target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12222263/2127125)

Hope this helps

Comment: i am looking for something a bit more elaborate (not a one page explanation though.) and a bit more contextual to my example .

Answer (score 0):

So my question was what is the below line doing:

```
if (this.$element[0] !== e.target && !this.$element.has(e.target).length)
```

lets evaluate it piece by piece ,

this.$element[0] - is an HTML element.

e.target - is an HTML object on which an event was executed eg. click , hover                            etc.

So the first condition is

if this particular element `this.$element[0]` is not equal to `!==` the element on which the event occured  `e.target` .

and the code looks as follows: `this.$element[0] !== e.target`

now coming to the secound condition:

```
!this.$element.has(e.target).length
```

! - the not operator

this.@element - a Jquery element

has - A jquery method/function

length - returns the length .

so basically we are saying if this particular element `this.$element` , has the element on which the event occurred `has(e.target)` , ............. Errrrrr , i am pretty much lost after this , somebody come and complete my answer . :) what is `.length` doing in the end ? , also how is ! effecting the condition .

**P.S. Give me a few mins , i'll be back with my updated answer . just trying to figure out the last condition. just a few mins . :D**

Comment: It's been a few minutes... did you have any update? :)